# preg_replace php clean string

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-replace, preg-match

I have problem with regular expressions in laravel, This is the string who need to be fixed:

```
$testString = '"""
\n
                                            Brisel --  Proizvođači mleka iz raznih evropskih zemalja poprskali su danas zgradu EU u Briselu mlekom u prahu, u znak protesta zbog krize u njihovom sektoru. \n

"""';
```

I want to get string like this:

```
$testString = Brisel- Proizvođači mleka iz raznih evropskih zemalja poprskali su danas zgradu EU u Briselu mlekom u prahu, u znak protesta zbog krize u njihovom sektoru.
```

**Edit:** I found the solution.

```
$str = str_replace(array('\n', '\r', '"'), '', $testString);
$str = strip_tags($str);
$testString = preg_replace(array("/^[A-Z a-z 0-9\\/\\\\.'\"]+/", "/\s+/"), ' ', $str);

  echo $testString;
  dd($testString);
```

Comment: please properly indent your code

Comment: What is the difference between the two strings? Those line breaks? Or the `\n` character? It currently is not clear what your actual situation is, since the first definition you gave is not even valid php... So please take the time to revise your question so that others can  understand what you actually ask. There is an `edit` link below your question for that. _Use it..._

Comment: When I did dd($testString) I got this string but with (\n with a lot empty spaces and double qoutes) on start point of string and on the end of string. I just want to be clean string without \n and double qoutes.

Comment: Use ```trim($testString, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\"")```. [trim documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: No, nothing fixed when I did 'dd($testString)'...important thing is it need to be clean string when I did 'dd($testString)'.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is inside single quote, `\n` is not interpreted in this case, it stays `\n`, not linefeed.
To remove it you could do:

```
$testString = '"""
\n
                                            Brisel --  Proizvođači mleka iz raznih evropskih zemalja poprskali su danas zgradu EU u Briselu mlekom u prahu, u znak protesta zbog krize u njihovom sektoru. \n

"""';
$testString = preg_replace('/^[\\\n\W]+|[\\\n\W]+$/u', '', $testString);
echo $testString,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Brisel --  Proizvođači mleka iz raznih evropskih zemalja poprskali su danas zgradu EU u Briselu mlekom u prahu, u znak protesta zbog krize u njihovom sektoru
```